# Generate PDF report in Jasper in batch of 50 or so?

Tags: jasper-reports, pdf-generation

I have one report that I have designed in Jasper report.The problem right now I am facing is with high quantity of data.Client wanted to generate that report in batch of 50 or preferably (no of pages) as input parameter.Is there any in-build provision in Jasper report that will generate report(in pdf format) in batches.
I know about two ways:

1. Have input parameter that will specify batch no in report query.
2. Else only provide that many rows that we wanted in generated PDF by
   bringing these rows in Java.

But any alternative to this problem is highly appreciated as I high very limited knowledge Jasper report.